# Fitting the Poisson distribution

Tags: r

I was unable to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator and BIC for the Poisson distribution.. I was able to get the histogram but couldn't superimpose a kernel density estimate on it.

Can you please tell me where I went wrong?

```
x.pois<-rpois(Y1, 20)
hist(x.pois, breaks=100,freq=FALSE)
lines(density(Y1, bw=0.8), col="red")
library(MASS)
fitdistr(Y1,densfun="pois")
my.mle<-fitdistr(Y1, densfun="poison")
print(my.mle)
BIC(my.mle)
```

Comment: What is the object `Y1`?

Comment: Toxic code? Presumably you mean `poisson` rather than `poison`.

Comment: Please note that it's considered better form to [edit your existing question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171803/new-question-or-edit-existing-question-with-new-sample-code?lq=1) rather than [asking a new, almost identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984577/poisson-distribution-in-r) one ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to (1) spell "poisson" correctly; (2) use `x.pois` (the Poisson sample), not `Y1` (which should be the number of points you're trying to sample, based on your code example).

Note that kernel density estimates, and histograms, of discrete distributions don't necessarily make a lot of sense.

```
Y1 <- 100
set.seed(101) ## for reproducibility
x.pois<-rpois(Y1, 20)
hist(x.pois, breaks=100,freq=FALSE)
lines(density(x.pois, bw=0.8), col="red")
library(MASS)
(my.mle<-fitdistr(x.pois, densfun="poisson"))
##      lambda  
##   20.6700000 
##  ( 0.4546427)
BIC(my.mle)
## [1] 572.7861
```

**update**: [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984577/poisson-distribution-in-r) makes it clear that `Y1` really is your sample, in which case the whole `rpois()`-sampling thing is just a red herring.  In that case you should just leave out the first three lines, and substitute `Y1` for `x.pois`, in the code above.